# multiple key vault references in same ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy an ARM template with conditional logic to use two different key-vaults depending on the input. Each exists in a different subscription which is the issue..

(I'm using one template for prod and dev and deploying to different subscriptions accordingly)

`Master template variable
1. Key vault 1: /subid1/xxxxx/keyvault
2. Key vualt 2: /subid2/xxxx/keyvault`

`Nested template
"[If(x=y),/subid1/xxxxx/keyvault,/subid1/xxxxx/keyvault)]"`

So when deploying into subscrition 2 (subid2) as an example the error is:

`Code=KeyVaultParameterReferenceNotInTheSameTenant; Message=The specified KeyVault /subid1/xxxxx/keyvault is not in current tenant.`

So I get why the error message is flagging(I've declared a variable in another sub), but how can i get the validation to check what's being deployed as opposed to the variables or is there another way to achieve the same goal?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more a workaround than an answer but I just declared key-vault as a parameter in input a different value into the VSTS build definition. Not ideal as I wanted selected DEV to flow through all the pertinent settings, but works so closing.